# Display a container with linear gradient over a PageView in a stack keeping the PageView scrollable

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio, dart

I am developing an app like TikTok where I want to display some text on top and bottom of a video that is scrollable using a PageView.
I want to add a linear gradient of [black-white-white-black] on the PageView.

I tried using a Container inside an Expanded Widget so that it takes the max height and added Linear Gradient in the BoxDecoration. But after putting a Container, the PageView is no longer scrollable.

I have attached the code below, if there is any other possible approach for getting that gradient please help me with that.

```
class FeedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'FeedScreen';

  const FeedScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FeedScreen> createState() => _FeedScreenState();
}

class _FeedScreenState extends State<FeedScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      endDrawer: CategoriesDrawer(),
      // drawer: MainDrawer(),
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(selectedIndex: 0),
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          Builder(
            builder: (context) => IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.grid_view_outlined,
                  color: Colors.black, size: 24),
              onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer(),
              tooltip: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).openAppDrawerTooltip,
            ),
          ),
        ],
        leading: const Image(
          image: AssetImage(
            'assets/images/logo.png',
          ),
          height: 28,
        ),
        toolbarHeight: 36,
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        // top: false,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                // color: const Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0.5),
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                  end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  colors: [
                    Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(1),
                    Colors.transparent,
                    Colors.transparent,
                    Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(1),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              child: PageView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                children: const [
                  Feed(
                      video_url:
                          'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/bee.mp4'),
                  Feed(
                      video_url:
                          'https://citjos3.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videos/1605781113_1369820376withSound.mp4'),
                  Feed(
                      video_url:
                          'https://citjos3.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videos/1606913499_1670916107withSound.mp4'),
                  // Feed(video_url: 'https://citjos3.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videos/1611855565_1738601504withSound.mp4'),
                  // Feed(video_url: 'https://citjos3.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videos/1608188894_1415136971withSound.mp4'),
                  // Feed(video_url: 'https://citjos3.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videos/1608189698_416483317withSound.mp4'),
                  // Feed(video_url: 'https://citjos3.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videos/1608190662_1789437565withSound.mp4'),
                  // Feed(video_url: 'https://citjos3.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videos/1608190955_1992811495withSound.mp4'),
                  // Feed(video_url: 'https://citjos3.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/videos/1608211397_1670759579withSound.mp4'),
                  // Feed(video_url: ''),
                  // Feed(video_url: ''),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  // color: const Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0.5),
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    colors: [
                      Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(1),
                      Colors.transparent,
                      Colors.transparent,
                      Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(1),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                child: Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Text(
                              'Subscribed',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 18,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Text(
                              'Global',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 18,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Text(
                              'Local',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 18,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the output]

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the overlay gradient widget with an IgnorePointer widget